# Unable to connect Flask app to SQL Server container in Docker Compose

Tags: python, sql-server, docker, docker-compose

I am having issues connecting my Flask application to a SQL Server container using Docker Compose. The init.sql script doesn't seem to create the expected database, and my Flask app encounters a login timeout error.

Here's a simplified overview of my setup:

```
#Docker Compose File (docker-compose.yml):

version: '3'

services:
  sqlserver:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: YourStrong@Passw0rd
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
    volumes:
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    ports:
      - "14500:1433"
    networks:
      - app_network

  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - sqlserver
    networks:
      - app_network

networks:
  app_network:
    driver: bridge
```

```
#Flask Application (app.py):

# app.py

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import pyodbc

app = Flask(__name__)

# SQL Server connection config
server = 'sqlserver' 
database = 'recipes'
username = 'SA'
password = 'YourStrong@Passw0rd' 


conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server; SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Create recipes table
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE recipes (id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(100), instructions VARCHAR(1000))")

@app.route("/recipes", methods=['POST'])
def add_recipe():
  name = request.json['name']
  instructions = request.json['instructions']
  
  cursor.execute("INSERT INTO recipes (name, instructions) VALUES (?, ?)", (name, instructions))
  conn.commit()
  
  return jsonify({
    "message": "Recipe added successfully!"
  })

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

```
#init.sql

USE master;
CREATE DATABASE TestDB;
```

However, when I run my Flask app, I encounter the following error:

```
2023-11-11 19:12:30 pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I have verified that the database is created when connecting through SQL Server Management Studio, but the Flask app fails to connect and the database I want to create in init.db is not created.

> also I'm using `docker-compose build` and after that I'll use `docker-compose up`  to create an image

Can someone please guide me on what might be causing this issue and how I can resolve it? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not going to add an answer because I'm not familiar with this stack, but I can see you're using a non-standard port (14500) for the database container. My guess is you need to include this port in the connection string. 

Side-note: if you're using python, why not PostgreSQL and psycopg2 as a driver? (It's all open-source, better documented and widely used).

Comment: we're required to use mssql for database

Comment: Ah okay, just thought I'd mention an alternative.

Comment: did you try: `sqlserver,14500` as server name?

Comment: @siggemannen port 14500 is the port published on the Docker host (i.e.: host.docker.internal). Other containers within the same Docker network should be able to use the SQL Server container's exposed port, 1433.

Comment: If you monitor the Docker logs output from the SQL Server container do you see any error messages when the Flask container attempts to connect?

Comment: Aside... _Important The SA_PASSWORD environment variable is deprecated. Use MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD instead._ Ref: [Run SQL Server Linux container images with Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker).

Comment: Has `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql` ever actually been implemented in SQL Server for Docker images? (As far as I know that's only something in MySQL and PostgreSQL images.) The [mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) recommends an alternative initialization procedure using `entrypoint.sh` and `setup.sql` files.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning oh, makes sense, i never remember the order in docker =) Then i'll be guessing the server doesn't have time to start up properly?